# multiple edit text field on click problems

Tags: android, android-edittext

Now, I created a number pad and I have multiple edit text and I have set the clicks for the numbers but they are only for the first edit text but I can't set it for the other editTexts

Here's a picture that explains what I mean

[image]

**My second question is:** as displayed to you in the text watcher that I'm showing that when the four digits are entered the focus is no longer required in any edit text and it is working but I want the focus to 
come back if I have to delete all of the four digits how to do this?

Here's the code I'm using

Main Activity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9;
    EditText edit1, edit2, edit3, edit4;
    ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edit1 = findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        edit2 = findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        edit3 = findViewById(R.id.edit3);
        edit4 = findViewById(R.id.edit4);

        btn0 = findViewById(R.id.button0);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btn6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btn7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
        btn8 = findViewById(R.id.button8);
        btn9 = findViewById(R.id.button9);
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.button_delete_delete);


        btn0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn0.getText());
            }
        });
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn1.getText());
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn2.getText());
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn3.getText());
            }
        });
        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn4.getText());
            }
        });
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn5.getText());
            }
        });
        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn6.getText());
            }
        });
        btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn7.getText());
            }
        });
        btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn8.getText());
            }
        });
        btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText(btn9.getText());

            }
        });
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edit1.setText("");
                edit2.setText("");
                edit3.setText("");
                edit4.setText("");

            }
        });

        edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() == 0) {
                    edit1.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() == 1) {
                    edit2.requestFocus();
                }

                edit2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (s.length() == 0) {
                            edit1.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (s.length() == 1) {
                            edit3.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                });
                edit3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (s.length() == 0) {
                            edit1.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (s.length() == 1) {
                            edit4.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                });

                edit4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (s.length() == 0) {
                            edit1.requestFocus();

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (s.length() == 1) {
                            edit1.setFocusable(false);
                            edit1.setSelected(false);
                            edit2.setFocusable(false);
                            edit2.setSelected(false);
                            edit3.setFocusable(false);
                            edit3.setSelected(false);
                            edit4.setFocusable(false);
                            edit4.setSelected(false);
                        } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                            edit1.setFocusable(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are adding the "addTextChangedListener" on "edit2', "edit3" and "edit4"  inside the "afterTextChanged" method of "edit1"?

Comment: It works fine the problem is i need put the numbers in each focused edit text I CAN'T DO THAT

Answer (score 0):

```html
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_container_buttons);
ViewGroup parrentViewTextBoxes = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_container_TextBoxes);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
if(child instanceof Button)
{
Button button = (Button) child;
button.setText(i);
button. setOnClickListener
( new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
TextView textBox = (TextView) parrentViewTextBoxes.findViewWithTag(“edittext_”+i);
textBox.setText(i);
}
});
}
}
```